# How to truncate a line between 2 points?

Tags: java, math, vector, java-canvas

I want to draw a line on a canvas. Therefore I use two clicks from the user to define start point `S` and end point `E`.

```
ctx.moveTo(sx, sy);
ctx.lineTo(ex, ey);
```

I further want to substract a static offset on both sides of the line, eg `static int offset = 10;`
My problem is: how can I know about the direction (north, east, south, west) to which I have to add or substract the offset?

If the line goes from top to bottom, I would have to apply `(0, +10)` on the start point S, and `(0, -10)` on the end point. Getting mor complicated when the line goes diagonal through the coordinate space.

Probably that might be a "simple" mathematical problem, but I'm missing the right keywords to find any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use some basic math.

1. Find the x and y displacements
2. Find the angle theta
3. Create a displacement vector
4. Add or take this from your points

Let me know if this doesn't work.

```
int offset = 10;

int[] point1 = {15, 25}; //start point
int[] point2 = {42, 37}; //end point

int xDisplacement = point2[0] - point1[0];
int yDisplacement = point2[1] - point1[1];

double theta = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(yDisplacement, xDisplacement));        

double[] diplacementVector = {offset*Math.cos(theta), offset*Math.sin(theta)};

point1[0] += diplacementVector[0];
point1[1] += diplacementVector[1];

point2[0] -= diplacementVector[0];
point2[1] -= diplacementVector[1];
```

Comment: I understand, that gets me going!